# Getting the mouse cursor speed in C#

Tags: c#

I was sucecssful regarding changing the mouse speed with C# with the help of this article: http://www.sparrowtail.com/changing-mouse-pointer-speed-c.

Now I also want to get the current mouse speed. I tried to change `const uint SPI_GETMOUSESPEED` to `0x0072` and also to `0x0070` hoping that this would be the right adress. Microsoft documentation says that the adress (at least in C++) is `0x70` however it is not possbile for me to get the right adress on the internet.

My function:

```
private int GetMouseSpeed()
    {

        const uint SPI_GETMOUSESPEED = 0x0070;
        uint mouseSpeed = 0;

        SystemParametersInfo
        (
            SPI_GETMOUSESPEED,
            0,
            mouseSpeed,
            0
        );

        return (int) mouseSpeed;
    }
```

Comment: According to the MSDN `The pvParam parameter must pointer to an integer that receives a value which ranges between 1 (slowest) and 20 (fastest).`

Comment: Added my current function to the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all possible values of `uiAction` on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx). `SPI_GETMOUSESPEED` value is `0x70`. Plus, you need to pass pointer to an integer that receives a value. In the code below I did it using the unsafe `&` operator. In order to compile it, you need to check `Allow unsafe context` in the build settings of your project.

```
public const UInt32 SPI_GETMOUSESPEED = 0x0070;

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern Boolean SystemParametersInfo(
    UInt32 uiAction,
    UInt32 uiParam,
    IntPtr pvParam,
    UInt32 fWinIni);

static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    int speed;
    SystemParametersInfo(
        SPI_GETMOUSESPEED,
        0,
        new IntPtr(&speed),
        0);
    Console.WriteLine(speed);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tried to realize the same thing in C++ and already knew about the needed pointer to get the speed but didn't knew how to realize a pointer in C#.

Comment: @chris579, using unsafe code is not required in this case. Just make pvParam a ref parameter (ref UInt32 pvParam).