# is there any way to check mouse sensitivity, i.e high, medium, low?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

i am working on a lock screen project and want to check for mouse sensitivity on lock screen,
is there any way to check the mouse sensitivity in c#. any function that checks if sensitivity was high medium or low, anything like this

Comment: read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964472/getting-the-mouse-cursor-speed-in-c-sharp) SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [SystemInformation.MouseSpeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousespeed(v=vs.110).aspx), but `This property is supported only on Windows 98, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows 2000, Windows XP, and the Windows Server 2003 family.`.

Give it a try on your target platform and see if it works.

You can also try the native call, see [Do I need 2 different PInvokes to Get and Set mouse speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003305/do-i-need-2-different-pinvokes-to-get-and-set-mouse-speed)